# Error updating WCF service reference in silverlight project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, wcf, silverlight-4.0

I an working on a website build in silverlight that use wcf services to communicate with business layer.

Previously i am working on **windows xp, 32 bit** system. Few days earlier i am migrated to **win 7, 64 bit** system along with same project.

I able to run the project with some changes in IIS. But now i change a service method parameters and i want these changes to be reflected in silverlight project but i am getting error while **updating** the service.

I tried to **remove** the reference so that on adding reference again, conflict will be resolved but **same error shown on adding the reference.**

Below is the snapshot of the error message.

[image]

As you can see i am running the visual studio with administrator role so i got the full read/write permissions.

Meanwhile i check the option of **"View in Browser"** for that service, and it shows no error, service is fine.

Comment: Its better if you delete and add reference

Comment: @Sajeetharan i already tried it but got the same error on adding the reference

Comment: please delete the reference from the servicereferences config file and update again.

Comment: @Sajeetharan tried your suggestion results in same error

Comment: are you able to invoke the service through svcutil.exe

Comment: @Sajeetharan nup, i tried but it gives me error: 1.The document was understood but it could not be processed.
2.The WSDL document contains links that could not be resolved.

Comment: then you should check the service

Comment: @Sajeetharan How do you propose i do it ? I know only one way that is to check service in browser, and service is doing fine with that option.

Comment: its hard to tell unless you post about the service

Comment: @Sajeetharan what info do you need about service ?

Comment: @Sajeetharan A wcf service, hosted in a web project, used in silverlight project and fetches data from library project.

Comment: @Sajeetharan Funny thing is his service is still running with old methods, but if you want to add new, it simply did't allow it.

Answer (score -1):

Had the same problem, the reason turned out to be:
**One of the object from the server side that was returned to the client had a parameter added to its constructor which meant it no longer had a default constructor.**

It wasn't until someone had to change a service method and update the references that we hit the error, which was weeks after the constructor change was done. I was sent down the road of the mismatch bindings and lost a lot of time before figuring that one out!

Comment: Well, he doesn't directly ask a question; he's having a problem and looking for a solution. I had the exact same problem and I tell how I was able to solve it.

Comment: Thanks. The infamous phrase "I had the same problem" and a wall of text confused me. Fixed that.